# How to change div id dynamically based on a function in Typescript?

Tags: angular

Currently, I display a circular image on the left side of the list of records. I need this id property to be dynamic, it should be displayed based on the conditions in the function written in typescript. My actual requirement is based on 5 conditions, the circular image must change its colour.

Now the styling property is present in respective components CSS.

Please help me how to proceed

```html
<div id="circle1">
  <div id="h3">
    <em class="" style="font-size: 0.7rem;font-weight: bold;"></em>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using ngStyle?
https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can accomplish this, I will highlight three:

- View Child
- Id binding
- Class binding

If you really have to change the id, I would recommend binding the id of the div. If your only concern is to change the style, I would use classes instead.
[Stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-yahmzq.stackblitz.io)

#### View Child

You can use the [ViewChild decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to get a reference to your `div` element and change its id. Note that the ViewChild is not available in the constructor or `ngOnInit()`, but starting from `ngAfterViewInit` (see [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)).

Template:

```
<div id="test" #target>
  Id based
</div>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild("target") targetDiv: ElementRef;

changeId() {
  this.targetDiv.nativeElement.id = "new-id";
}
```

---

#### Id Binding

A simpler approach is to directly bind the id property.

Template:

```
<div [id]="getId()">
  Id binding
</div>
```

Component:

```
condition: boolean = false;

getId() {
  return this.condition ? "new-id" : "test";
}
```

---

#### Class based

Since you want to change the style, it actually doesn't make sense to change the id. It would be more appropriate to simply set the correct css classes.

Template:

```
<div [ngClass]="getClass()">
  Class based
</div>
```

Component:

```
condition: boolean = false;

getClass() {
  return this.condition ? "yellow" : "green";
}
```